# MacBook needs to close open lid for network to work again?

Tags: macos, network, monterey

I use the MacBook in clamshell mode most of the time. It works well, most of the time, whenever I open or close the laptop, then connect to WiFi. However, sometimes whenever I open the lid the network is not working after connecting to WiFi. I wait for some time or ping and get no response. Then I have to close and open the lid back, only then does the network get connected.

Any workaround or setting that can be done for this issue?

Comment: How often do you restart the MacBook and how often do you shut it down fully?

Comment: Very rare, whenever the battery drained. Always on sleep when not in use. Would be around once or twice a month or longer.

Comment: I would recommend restarting it much more often, such as every week or so. It clears the memory and restarts the hardware (such as wifi drivers) and usually fixes any weird bugs happening to your computer. Restarting only takes about a minute and your performance speed will be much better as well.

Comment: @mpp thanks for the suggestion.   However in this case, everytime booting up, it take much more time to load all the apps needed for development. 